# What are correct content-type for spreadsheets, presentations and compressed files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, mime-types, content-type

What are correct content-type for spreadsheets, presentations and compressed files ?

List of content types for spreadsheets, presentations and compressed files ?

Comment: Why did you tag it with "ruby"?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [mime-types](http://www.wrensoft.com/forum/showthread.php?t=2834)

Comment: Always glad to help everyone :) (I also used this link to get content type of .docx files)